# OrientDB Repeated Corruption

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases, nosql

I'm trying to build a Java application using Wicket as a front end and OrientDB as the database.

**Three times today, my databases have been corrupted, once while trying to perform a backup.** I am confident that I am doing something wrong. There appears to be a console command to repair the database but I cannot connect to the database to use it.

My Java web app connects to my graph database using the Graph API. At first I was using plocal mode, but now I am using remote even though the DB is local to my box.

I am also connecting to OrientDB via the provided console and the web interface. Here is the error message I am receiving:

```
orientdb> connect remote:localhost/grctestdb admin password
Connecting to database [remote:localhost/grctestdb] with user 'admin'...
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/opt/orientdb/databases/grctestdb' with mode=rw
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Cannot load database's configuration. The database seems to be corrupted.
Error: com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: You cannot access outside the file size (0 bytes). You have requested portion 0-4 bytes. File: File: database.ocf os-size=1024, stored=0, filled=0, max=0
```

The only connection between the three corruption events is that I am always notified of the corruption via the Console first, then my application reports the same error in a stack trace the next time I fire it up. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the last thing I did was issue the `exit` command from the console while connected to the database. Would not issuing `disconnect` be enough to corrupt it?

Comment: Which version of OrientDB do you have?

Comment: Did you create grctestdb database as memory, local or plocal?

Comment: All of them have been plocal.